# Only Show Edit Button On Owner's Posts - Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have a Django project with posts and the ability to edit posts.
On the main index page, I am showing all posts, like a news feed.
Currently anyone can edit any post, but I want to make it so that only the owner of the post can edit. I'm just not sure how to write the urls.py file since I'm using:

```
path("", views.index, name="index"),
```

I would probably need to pass either the post id or the username to this, but I'm not sure how to write it. I tried:

```
path("index", views.index, name="index"), 
path("index/<str:pk>", views.index, name="index"),
path("index/<str:username>", views.index, name="index"),
```

But I get errors.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    list_of_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('id').reverse()
    paginator = Paginator(list_of_posts, 10)
    num = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    get_page_num = paginator.get_page(num)

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "list_of_posts": list_of_posts,
        "get_page_num": get_page_num,
    })
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, 
null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author', 
    null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)      
    like = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,  blank=True, related_name="liked_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.username
```

html to show edit button. I've tried:

```
{% if post.username == request.user.username %}
              <button class="btn-btn primary" my-id="{{i.id}}" id="ebutton- 
{{i.id}}" onclick="edit_form(this)" >Edit</button>
              <br><br><br> 
{% endif %}
```

Full html of this page:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
<br>
 <h3> <center> Welcome. Here is your news feed: </center> </h3>
 <br>

{% for i in get_page_num %}

<div class='card mb-3' style="max-width: 530px;" id="card-posts">

  <div class="row no-gutters">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'profile' 
     username=i.username %}">{{i.username}}</a></h5>
          
    <span id="textinfo-{{i.id}}" 
    class="post">{{i.text}}</span> <br> 
    <textarea my-id="{{i.id}}" id="edit-me-{{i.id}}" 
    style="display:none;" class="form-control 
    textarea" row="3">{{i.text}}</textarea>
          
     <br>
     <p class="card-text">{{i.timestamp}}</p>

      <div class="like mt-1">
      <img my-id="{{i.id}}" id="is-it-liked-{{i.id}}" 
      class="like-class"
  
      {% if not request.user in i.like.all %}
  
       clicked="no" 
       src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/452/white-heart.png"
  
         {%else%}
  
         clicked="yes" 
        src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/452/red-heart.png"
  
         {%endif%}
          /> <span id="post-count-{{i.id}}">{{i.like.count}}. 
          </span>
          </div>

           <br>
          {% if request.user == post.username %}
          <button class="btn-btn primary" my-id="{{i.id}}" 
     id="ebutton-{{i.id}}" onclick="edit_form(this)" 
  >Edit</button>
    <br><br><br> 
          {% endif %}

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

{% endfor %}
<br><br>

<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
  {% if get_page_num.has_previous %}  
      <a href="?page={{ get_page_num.previous_page_number }}" 
class="page-link">Previous</a>
  {% else %}
  
  <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page- 
link">Previous</a></li>
  {% endif %}

 {% if get_page_num.has_next %}
 <a href="?page={{ get_page_num.next_page_number }}" class="page- 
link">Next</a>
 {% else %}

  <a class="page-link">Next</a>
 {% endif %}
</span>
</div>
{% endblock %}


 {% block script %} <script src="{% static 
 'network/network.js'%}"></script> {% endblock %}
```

With this way I need to pass username to the url but I cannot, without getting errors.
Overall I'm just looking for advice, on how to make the edit button only appear on posts that the current user is an owner on. So that way no one can edit anyone else's posts.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show all posts and only allow a post author to edit it, you need to inject all posts and the request user in your template context. Then in your template iterate through the posts and check if the author is equal to the request user before showing the edit button. But first you need a foreign key in your post model that refers to the author.

**Urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [path("index/", views.index, name="index")]
```

**Views**

```py
def index(request):
    list_of_posts = Post.objects.order_by('-id')
    request_user = request.user

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "list_of_posts": list_of_posts,
        "request_user": request_user
    })
```

**Models**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='posts')
    # Other fields
```

**Template**

```html
{% if post.user == request_user %}
    <!--Show the edit button-->
{% endif %}
```

You can also access directly the request object in your template:

```html
{% if post.user == request.user %}
    <!--Show the edit button-->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @ RedWheelbarrow I tried the url as you put it - but I get django 404 error not found. For accessing the request object in the template, I also did this. My model is called Post and I have 'username' as an attribute so I did {% if post.username == request.user %} but the edit button still does not show on all posts on that page.

Comment: @user14567126 If `Post.username` field contains the username of the author, use this condition: `{% if post.username == request.user.username %}`. Or if you prefer to inject the request user in the context of the serializer: `{% if post.username == request_user.username %}`. If `Post.username` does not contain a string, please provide the details of your `Post` and `User` model.

Comment: @ RedWheelbarrow I updated this page with my model and a simplified view that I tried. In the html, I tried your suggestion as well as others, like: if post.username == request.user.username, if post.username == request.username.username etc. I now don't get any errors, but the edit button either appears on all posts or it doesn't appear on any posts. I just need it to appear on the posts the request.user is an author of.

Comment: @user14567126 Try this: `{% if request.user == post.username %}`. If this doesn't work, please provide the code of your template as well (especially the part where you iterate though posts).

Comment: @ RedWheelbarrow I updated the page to have my full html file. I am using pagination and part of that code is used to iterate through posts. I originally thought that wouldn't make a difference so I did not include it. But you're probably right, sorry for the confusion. My view is updated too.

Comment: I actually ended up solving it, you were right @ RedWheelbarrow. I just needed to pay attention to the rest of the html page and it had to do with the pagination. When I said 'for i in get_page_num' I needed to put i in front of username. So the correct html part is {% if request.user == i.username %}.   Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add

`{% if request.user == i.username %}`

because I was looping in the html page, `for i in get_page_num:`. I did not previously have the i.

Answer (score 0):

```html
{% if request.user == post.author %}
    <button>Delete</button>
{% endif %}
```

This assumes that you have a `Post` model with an attribute of `author`